# CGAL modify existing polygon

Tags: c++, cgal

I'm currently working on an algorithm which operates on a `std::vector<Kernel::Point_2>` point set *P*. As an input, I have a polygon (`Polygon_2<Kernel>`), which has a subset of *P* on its boundary. The rest of the points lay on the exterior of the given polygon.

I want to iteratively extend the polygon, which means essentially removing an edge `(p,q)` and insert two new edges `(p,v)` `(v,q)`. I pick the vertex *v* so that the empty triangle `T(p,v,q)` has a maximal area. This is equivalent to placing the vertex *v* between *p* and *q* in the underlying sorted vertex list (boundary) of the polygon. Currently, I copy all points of the polygon into a vector, modify the vector and reinitialize a new polygon with the boundary vector. Is there a way to modify the boundary of an existing polygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the function [`insert`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon/classCGAL_1_1Polygon__2.html#a549bfe1f56e4a8f7c4ac3676205e4007)?

Comment: Maybe keeping a track of the vertices of the polygon in  a map<Point, vertex> to easily retrive them, and editing the polygon with insert() and erase().

Comment: Thank you this worked. Is it possible to modify the order of points of a polygon without manually erasing and reinserting the point? E.g. with `std::iter_swap()`?

Comment: if you use the method `container()` you basically have access to the underlying vector so you are free to do whatever you want.